# How to indent lines using recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion, indentation

Trying to achieve something like this using recursion:

```
if (m > n) return;
Foo 1          // no tabs
   Foo 2       // \t
      Foo 3    // \t\t
   Foo 2       // \t
Foo 1          // no tabs
```

I have a function that takes  2 parameters: `void indent(int m, int n);`
*(calling number from m to n).*

So far I figured this much out:

- **As long as m <= n, keep calling the function. (base case)**
- Print the first line without any tabs **setw(0)**
- Call the function recursively with m+1 increment. **setw(4*m)**
- Print the first line without any tabs (again). **setw(0)**

Am I on the right track? Is my pseudocode correct at least?

Also, is there any way to express tabs numerically? I can't think of any way to use tab \t using either recursion or iteration.

**Update**: *I figured it out :). `cout << setw(4*m);` right before `cout << "Foo";` does the trick. On first call m=0 so setw(0), on 2nd call setw(4), then setw(8) and so on. Now I just have to print the text backward to 0 tabs.*

Comment: How will you ever get any indentation if you never print any indentation? ;-) Also, looks like you could get a stack overflow since there's no base case!

Comment: It should be in your pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are on the right path.  You would just want your recursive method to check when m == n, you would only print the line once rather then twice and then unroll.

Answer (score 1):

This will work perfectly.

```
void indent( int m, int n )
{
  PrintTabs( m ); // Forward Printing

  if ( m < n )
  {
    indent( m + 1, n );
    PrintTabs( m ); // Backward Printing
  }
}

int main()
{
  indent( 0, MAX );
  return 0;
}
```